Vite/Preact non-hardcoded proxy best practice
I have a preact frontend with a FastAPI backend. Everything works fine on localhost.
But I had problems reaching my server, from another ip-address, which i solved by changing the fetches from http://localhost:8000 to the ip address of the server machine. E.g. http://192.168.0.99:8000.
I am using the server on a raspberry pi which can change network, which is why i cannot use a static ip-address in the proxy. That's how i came up with the following solution:
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import preact from '@preact/preset-vite';
import os from 'os';

function getLocalIpAddress() {
    const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    for (const name of Object.keys(interfaces)) {
        for (const iface of interfaces[name]) {
            if (iface.family === 'IPv4' && !iface.internal) {
                return "http://" + iface.address + ":8000";
            }
        }
    }
    return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
}

function getLocalIpAddressWs() {
    const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    for (const name of Object.keys(interfaces)) {
        for (const iface of interfaces[name]) {
            if (iface.family === 'IPv4' && !iface.internal) {
                return "ws://" + iface.address + ":8000";
            }
        }
    }
    return 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000';
}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [preact()],
    server: {
        port: 3000,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: getLocalIpAddress(), // Replace with your backend server URL
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
            },
            '/socket': {
                target: getLocalIpAddressWs(), // Replace with your backend server URL
                changeOrigin: true,
                rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/socket/, ''),
            },
        },
    },
});

Is this bad practice? Is there a better solution?

To remove redundancy in your code, you could unify getLocalIpAddress() and getLocalIpAddressWs() to something like:

function getLocalProxy(proxy) {
    const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    for (const name of Object.keys(interfaces)) {
        for (const iface of interfaces[name]) {
            if (iface.family === 'IPv4' && !iface.internal) {
                return `${proxy}://" + ${iface.address} + ":8000`;
            }
        }
    }
    return `${proxy}://127.0.0.1:8000`;
}


Also iface.address  could be prone to malicious URLs so you want to enforce same-origin restrictions in your application. Never worked with preact or vite, so I don't know the specifics here.
